# Remove window background from appcompat v21

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have a lot of overdraw in my app, which caused me to disable the window background completely. After upgrading to appcompat v21 the decorview has a solid color background again (its primaryColor). I tried the following to disable it:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Guidantswhite">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

or in my base theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Guidantswhite" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app's branding color (for the app bar) -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/bgo_highlight</item>
</style>
```

Would be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In my code I sent background for decorview for reason to set it for status bar. Maybe you have the same functionality?